# Live counter jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста есть такой скрипт.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.button_like', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var likes_count = $('#ajax-count-likedis');
        if($(this).attr('title')=='Нравится'){
            $.post('../stena/ps_love.php',{pid:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
                $this.text('Не нравится');
                $this.attr('title','Не нравится');
                $this.addClass("active_like");

                var likes = parseInt(likes_count.text())+1;
                likes_count.text(likes);
            });
        }else{
            if($(this).attr('title')=='Не нравится'){
                $.post('../stena/ps_love.php',{pid:$(this).attr('id'),action:'unlike'},function(){
                    $this.text('Нравится');
                    $this.attr('title','Нравится');
                    $this.removeClass("active_like");

                    var likes = parseInt(likes_count.text())-1;
                    likes_count.text(likes);
                });
             }
         }
    });
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста вот есть например 2-5 записей и при нажатии на кнопку нравится идет +1 но работает это если например вы поставили лайк на первую запись, а если на 2 то идет +1 все равно к 1 записи. Подскажите где ошибка?

Comment: Хорошо бы на структуру html взглянуть, а то есть некоторые сомнения по поводу элемента "*#ajax-count-likedis*". Если у вас несколько записей и под каждую свой вывод результатов счетчика лайков, то эти элементы должны иметь или уникальные id, или какой-то общий класс. И не очень понятна схема. У вас только одна кнопка, которая изначально "Нравится", а при повторном нажатии - "Не нравится". А что, если я сразу хочу минус влепить? Может всё-таки [сделать две кнопки][1]?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/u2va0a85/1/

Comment: @Deonis
Вот вывод кнопок нравиться и не нравиться

<?php
$pid=$post_id; //Post id - Post is "Hi everybody"
$uid=$myrow2['id']; //User id - User is "Subin Siby"
$sql=$bd->prepare("SELECT ps_id_fk,id_users FROM post_like WHERE ps_id_fk=? and id_users=?");
$sql->execute(array($pid, $uid));
// $all = $sql->rowCount();
if($sql->rowCount()==1){
?>
<a class="button_like active_like" id="<?=$post_id;?>" title="Не нравится"><?=$lang['DISLIKE'];?></a>
<? }else { ?>
<a  class="button_like" id="<?=$post_id;?>" title="Нравится"><?=$lang['LIKE'];?></a>
<?}?>

Comment: @Deonis
Так вывожу количество
<div id="ajax-count-likedis"><?=$run['love'];?></div>
идет подсчет из таблицы постов.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, всё это мало добавляет ясности. На одно странице у вас может быть выведена одна или несколько записей. А элемент с id "ajax-count-likedis" в единственном экземпляре или у каждой записи свой?

Comment: @Deonis У каждой свой это все выводиться в цикле.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, вот и я об этом. Один ID - может быть только у одного элемента в пределах страницы. Измените на класс или генерируйте уникальный id для каждой записи.

Comment: @Deonis Спасибо большое, не для глядел.